# Split string in Dataframe using Scala on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a logfile which has 100+ columns. Out of which I only needed two columns '_raw' and '_time', so i created loaded the logfile as "csv" DF.

Step 1:

```
scala> val log = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").load("soa_prod_diag_10_jan.csv")
log: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ARRAffinity: string, CoordinatorNonSecureURL: string ... 126 more fields]
```

Step 2:
I registered the DF as temp table
`log.createOrReplaceTempView("logs"`)

Step 3: I extracted my two required columns '_raw' and '_time'

```
scala> val sqlDF = spark.sql("select _raw, _time from logs")
sqlDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_raw: string, _time: string]

scala> sqlDF.show(1, false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|_raw                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |_time|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
|[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] [xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10] [ERROR] [OSB-473003] [oracle.osb.statistics.statistics] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b,0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Aggregation Server Not Available. Failed to get remote aggregator[[|null |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----+
only showing top 1 row
```

My requirement:

I need to split the string in the '_raw' column to produce 
[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] [xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10] [ERROR] [OSB-473003] [oracle.osb.statistics.statistics] [ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b] with column names a, b, c, d, e, f respectively

Also remove all null values from both '_raw' and '_time'

Your answers will appreciated :)

Comment: Please add one complete log string and mention what you need as _time.

Comment: From the below string in _raw column
[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] [xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10] [ERROR] [OSB-473003] [oracle.osb.statistics.statistics] [ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b]
Column A
[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] 
Column B
[xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10]
Column C
[ERROR]
Column D
[OSB-473003]
Column E
[oracle.osb.statistics.statistics]
Column F
[ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can you split function, and split the _raw by space. This will return an array and then you can extract the values from that array. You can also use regexp_extract function to extract values from log messages. Both the ways are shown below. I hope it is helpful.

```
//Creating Test Data
val df = Seq("[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] [xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10] [ERROR] [OSB-473003] [oracle.osb.statistics.statistics] [tid: [ACTIVE].ExecuteThread: '28' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [userId: <anonymous>] [ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b,0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] [tenant-name: GLOBAL] Aggregation Server Not Available. Failed to get remote aggregator[[")
  .toDF("_raw")

val splitDF = df.withColumn("split_raw_arr", split($"_raw", " "))
  .withColumn("A", $"split_raw_arr"(0))
  .withColumn("B", $"split_raw_arr"(1))
  .withColumn("C", $"split_raw_arr"(2))
  .withColumn("D", $"split_raw_arr"(3))
  .withColumn("E", $"split_raw_arr"(4))
  .drop("_raw", "split_raw_arr")

splitDF.show(false)

+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+
|A                              |B                   |C      |D           |E                                 |
+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+
|[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00]|[xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10]|[ERROR]|[OSB-473003]|[oracle.osb.statistics.statistics]|
+-------------------------------+--------------------+-------+------------+----------------------------------+

val extractedDF = df
  .withColumn("a", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\]",1))
  .withColumn("b", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",2))
  .withColumn("c", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",3))
  .withColumn("d", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",4))
  .withColumn("e", regexp_extract($"_raw", "\\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\]",5))
  .withColumn("f", regexp_extract($"_raw", "(?<=ecid: )(.*?)(?=,)",1))
  .drop("_raw")

+-----------------------------+------------------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|a                            |b                 |c    |d         |e                               |f                                            |
+-----------------------------+------------------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
|2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00|xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10|ERROR|OSB-473003|oracle.osb.statistics.statistics|92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b|
+-----------------------------+------------------+-----+----------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much...
Once more question;;;
[2019-01-10T23:59:59.998-06:00] [xx_yyy_zz_sss_ra10] [ERROR] [OSB-473003] [oracle.osb.statistics.statistics] ,0:1:5:3:6:4:6:4]”.
If i have extract ecid: 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b from above string then what index i will need to use to put it in column 'F'

Comment: For that I would ask you to go for the second approach, as there are multiple spaces in the data.

Comment: for the column f, if i need to just 92b39a8b-8234-4d19-9ac7-4908dc79c5ed-0000bd0b how would i approach?

Comment: It seems like a alpha-numeric value, but I am going to take everything from "ecid: " till "," as I am not sure all the values will be same. I have edited the answer.